How to configure a one-to-many relationship, using a join table, that doesn't reference the join table directly in EF Core 8
Sorry in advance if this has been asked before. First time posting on SO.
We're in the process of updating one of our data projects from .NET 4.7.2 to .NET 8.0. I'm having trouble trying to configure a one-to-many relationship between entities where a join/junction table is present.
I would like to skip the intermediary table and have a reference directly to the entity on the opposite end (same concept as a skip navigation for a many-to-many relationships).
Table structure and dummy data below.
CREATE DATABASE Scratch;

USE Scratch;

-- Table creation

CREATE TABLE Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage 
(
    Id int IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ContentLanguage PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Scratch.dbo.Genre 
(
    Id int IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(255)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Genre PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage_GenreMap 
(
    ContentLanguageId int IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    GenreId int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ContentLanguage_GenreMap PRIMARY KEY (ContentLanguageId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ContentLanguage_GenreMap_ContentLanguage FOREIGN KEY (ContentLanguageId) REFERENCES Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage(Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ContentLanguage_GenreMap_Genre FOREIGN KEY (GenreId) REFERENCES Scratch.dbo.Genre(Id)
);

-- Seed data

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage ON;

INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage (Id, Name) VALUES (0, N'English');
INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage (Id, Name) VALUES (1, N'French');
INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage (Id, Name) VALUES (2, N'Chinese');
INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage (Id, Name) VALUES (3, N'Dutch; Flemish');
INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage (Id, Name) VALUES (4, N'German');
INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage (Id, Name) VALUES (5, N'Italian');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage OFF;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Scratch.dbo.Genre ON;

INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.Genre (Id, Name) VALUES (0, N'English');
INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.Genre (Id, Name) VALUES (1, N'French');
INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.Genre (Id, Name) VALUES (2, N'Chinese');
INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.Genre (Id, Name) VALUES (3, N'Dutch; Flemish');
INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.Genre (Id, Name) VALUES (4, N'German');
INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.Genre (Id, Name) VALUES (5, N'Italian');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Scratch.dbo.Genre OFF;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage_GenreMap ON;

INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage_GenreMap (ContentLanguageId, GenreId) VALUES (0, 0);
INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage_GenreMap (ContentLanguageId, GenreId) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage_GenreMap (ContentLanguageId, GenreId) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage_GenreMap (ContentLanguageId, GenreId) VALUES (3, 3);
INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage_GenreMap (ContentLanguageId, GenreId) VALUES (4, 4);
INSERT INTO Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage_GenreMap (ContentLanguageId, GenreId) VALUES (5, 5);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Scratch.dbo.ContentLanguage_GenreMap OFF;

I've only tried reverse engineering using EFPT for now, not sure what else to configure or try. IF you have any suggestions, let me know.
Ideally, entities in a relationship will have a direct reference to the entity on the opposite end of the relationship without referencing the join table.
Any ideas on how to resolve this? If you have any other questions, let me know.
Thanks in advance.
I'm working with a highly coupled system and not in a position to remove the join table altogether since its couple with a some SQL procedures, automated reports, etc...

You can define your entities like below:
public class ContentLanguage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; } = new List<Genre>();
}


public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public ICollection<ContentLanguage> ContentLanguages { get; set; } = new List<ContentLanguage>();
}

Then configure DBContext like the below:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    
    modelBuilder.Entity<ContentLanguage>()
        .HasMany(cl => cl.Genres)
        .WithMany(g => g.ContentLanguages)
        .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
            "ContentLanguage_GenreMap", // Put the name of the join table you like
            join => join
                .HasOne<Genre>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("GenreId")
                .HasConstraintName("FK_ContentLanguage_GenreMap_Genre")
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade),
            join => join
                .HasOne<ContentLanguage>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("ContentLanguageId")
                .HasConstraintName("FK_ContentLanguage_GenreMap_ContentLanguage")
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        );
}

Then you can use the skip navigation property to query ContentLanguage and Genre without joining table explicitly.
Hope it helps :)

Thanks for the suggestion, that worked a treat. +1

Happy to help :)
